# Are vowel ligatures common in any disciplines these days?

Tags: orthography, ligature

Are there any areas of writing, literature or science where æ or œ are still used?  Are there contexts where they are still considered mandatory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that *history* and *linguistics* are two of them.

In the area of **history**, you will probably be better understood if you spell "[*Alfred* the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelfred)" instead of "Ælfrēd" - especially if you write for an audience of non specialists.  Although, this is a matter of personal taste; I prefer to see "[*Ælfric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86lfric_of_Eynsham)" rather than "*Alfric* of Eynsham", because having to deal with several spellings for the same name means more effort for the reader.
However, the use of the "Æ" is probably not mandatory in history.

In **linguistics** however things are different.
In studies pertaining to Old English, the use of the "Æ" is expected.
Besides, Old English modern spelling conventions has a [number of special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_language#Conventions_of_modern_editions) (ð, þ being the most common) which makes "æ (short)" or "ǣ (long)" just one of many typographical peculiarities.
In this case, trying to avoid the hassle of key sequences is the best way to make yourself unintelligible.

**Edit**
In addition, as JSBangs rightfully points out in his comment, the "æ" is one of the phonetic symbols needed to represent the sounds of the English language in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).
In which case it is also mandatory.

Comment: Additionally, many ligatures have a unique meaning in the International Phonetic Alphabet, though that's a special case.

Comment: Thw @JSBangs, I've edited the answer to include this case as well.

Comment: /[œ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel)/ is also an IPA symbol in addition to /[æ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel)/.

Comment: Technically, the Old English (and Danish and Norwegian) letter 'æ' is not a ligature: it is a letter which happens to have the same glyph as the Latin/French/English ligature. I remember heated discussion of this on one of the unicode mailing lists in around 1993. The case is different for 'œ'.

Comment: I'm not too sure: Please note this remark [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_language#Conventions_of_modern_editions): "*Before 800 the digraph ‹ae› is often found instead of ‹æ›. During the 8th century ‹æ› began to be used more frequently was standard after 800*."

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of œ ligatures in French like sœur (sister) and cœur (heart.)

What I've noticed is that in British English and American English some words are spelled differently, which leads me to believe that there was a ligature, as confirmed by Wikipedia (just now as you've sparked my interest on the subject).

For example, *mediæval* is now just spelled *mediaeval* in Britain and *medieval* in the States; *encyclopædia* is another one. One example of an *œ* ligature in English would be *fœtus* (or *fetus* in American English).

See [AE ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AE_ligature), and [OE ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OE_ligature).

I don't know if there are any known ligatures that exist in English today, but they are still common in French.

Comment: Actually, _mediaeval_ is reported as variant spelling of _medieval_ from both the NOAD, and the OED. It doesn't seem British English and American English make any difference for that word.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that computerisation has caused the end of ligatures. It's much easier just to type ae than bind a keyboard shortcut to the ligature version.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the decline of ligatures goes back a bit furher than that — certainly as far as typewriters, on which it was (usually) not just difficult but impossible to type ligatures.  But I seem to recall reading that it predates them too, though I’m afraid I can’t remember where I saw that.